# Caratheodory: Motivation

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

While reading Rudin's real and complex analysis I came across the following nice reasoning:

---

**Reasoning of Variation Measure**

Given a complex measure $\mu$ find its variation measure $|\mu|$ that is the smallest measure among all dominating measures.

This variation measure $|\mu|$ especially would have to satisfy:
$$|\mu|(E)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}|\mu|(E_k)\geq\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}|\mu(E_k)|\qquad E=\bigsqcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} E_k$$
That suggests to consider:
$$|\mu|(E):=\sup_{E=\bigsqcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}E_k}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}|\mu(E_k)|$$
And this turns out to be the desired variation measure.

**Reasoning of Measure Completion**

Given a countably additive set function $\mu$ find the extension to a complete measure $\mu_E$ that is its domain extends to a sigma algebra on which the extension becomes a complete measure.

*Now, is there a reasoning giving rise to Caratheodory's construction comparable in structure to the above one? I could think of something like:*

A new measurable set $A$ in this sense would certainly have to satisfy:
$$\mu_E(A)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(E_k)\qquad A=\bigsqcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}E_k$$
But then this new measurable sets especially also would have to satisfy:
$$\mu_E(A)+\mu_E(X\setminus A)=\mu(X)$$
But how to continue then?

Comment: Did you mean $\inf$ instead of $\sup$, $\sup$ gives measure of the whole space for any $E$? And reasoning similar to what exactly?

Comment: @Conifold: Oh that was a typo - corrected.

Comment: I do not see the connection of your question (about outer measures) to the concept of the variation measure $|\mu|$. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: @PhoemueX: oh no no that was a little bit misleading maybe what I meant was that is there a reasoning for caratheodory's construction *similar* to that of variation measures but just from the way of reasoning not conceptually

Comment: @PhoemueX: I edited the question hope it is clearer now...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if you have any class of sets $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathrm{Pot}(X)$ and any function $\mu :\mathcal{A} \to [0,\infty]$ and want to extend it to a measure $\mu^\ast$ on any $\sigma$-Algebra $\Sigma$, it has to satisfy

$$
\mu^\ast (E) \leq \sum_k \mu^\ast (E_k) = \sum_k \mu (E_k)
$$

for each $E \in \Sigma$ and $E_k \in \mathcal{A}$ with $E \subset E_k$.

In this sense, the outer measure $\mu^\ast$ used in the proof of the Caratheodory extension theorem is the "largest" candidate measure.

Now for $E,F \in \Sigma$ would satisfy

$$
\mu^\ast (F) = \mu^\ast(F \cap E) + \mu^\ast(F \cap E^c), \qquad (\dagger)
$$

because $ \mu^\ast$ is finitely additive on $\Sigma$.

There is quite a leap to now require $(\dagger)$ for **all** subsets $F$ in order to call $E$ "measurable", but this is justified, because (as the proof shows) it "works".

EDIT: For possible future readers: As this post ([Caratheodory: Measurability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916367/caratheodory-measurability-characterizations/916803#916803)) shows, one can restrict the condition in $(\dagger)$ to only requiring the identity for $F = X$ as long as $\mu^\ast$ is the outer measure induced by some $\sigma$-additive set function $\mu$ defined on an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ if $\mu^\ast (X)$ is finite.

**But** the (current) proof given there that this condition actually suffices is using Caratheodory's theorem and its proof in which $(\dagger)$ is still required to hold for all $F$.

Comment: I read in a slightly different situation that requiring $\dagger$ only for the absolutely necessary set $X$ itself would suffice ($\mu^*(A)+\mu^*(X\setminus A)=\mu^*(X)$). That would close the gap. Is this true?

Comment: Interesting question. I am not sure about that. In the case of $\mu^\ast (X) = \infty$ it will **not** be sufficient in general. In the case that $\mu^\ast (X)$ is finite, it could be the case. I just tried to "google" the question and found the following http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34007/demystifying-the-caratheodory-approach-to-measurability . Here, it is hinted implicitly that it might be enough to take $F=X$. Where did you find the statement?

Comment: Yes indeed it would make the whole reasoning concise. I found it in several negative and positive versions in Bogachev's Measure Theory volume 1. Actually I'm only interested in the finite case $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$.