# Measurability using a premeasure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set, $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra on $X$, and $l$ be a premeasure on $\mathcal{A}$ such that $l(X)< \infty$. Let $\mu^{*}$ be the outer measure generated by $l$. We wish to show that a set $A \subset X$ is $\mu^{*}$-measurable if and only if $$(\dagger)    \>\>\>\>\mu^{*}(A)=l(X)-\mu^{*}(A^{C}). $$

(The outer measure $\mu^{*}$ is defined by $\mu^{*}(E)=\inf\{\sum l(A_{j}) : E \subset \bigcup A_{j} , A_{j} \in \mathcal{A}\}$)

Showing measurability implies $(\dagger)$ is straight-forward. I am, however, having trouble showing the reverse direction. I *had* a nice proof, but then I realized that $A$ is not necessarily in the algebra--which obviously ruined the whole thing!! Any help would be great. (Note: I did indeed see that this question had been asked. However, the poster who answered assumed that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, but we don't know that $\bigcup A_{j}$ belongs to $\mathcal{A}$!)

Comment: If you are talking about my answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916367/caratheodory-measurability-characterizations/916803#916803, I am **not** using that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-Algebra, but only that the class of $\mu^\ast$ measurable sets is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains $\mathcal{A}$.